# How to use IUniqueValueRenderer for empty geodatabase point file with ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#

I have empty geodatabase file with point geometry created programmatically. I have style file with several symbols.

I basically want to add all these symbols to my shapefile before creating features/geometry in shapefile. So when user starts editing he can select any of those symbols and drop on map (basically part of Add-in).

Using `IStyleGallery` I loop through all the symbols:

```
IEnumStyleGalleryItem enumStyleGalleryItem = styleGallery.get_Items("Marker Symbols", filePath, null);
enumStyleGalleryItem.Reset();
IStyleGalleryItem styleItem = enumStyleGalleryItem.Next();

while (styleItem != null)
{
   ISymbol symbol = styleItem.Item as ISymbol;
   IUniqueValueRenderer uniqueValueRenderer = new UniqueValueRendererClass();
   uniqueValueRenderer.AddValue(name, null, symbol);

   ?????
   some code to add all these symbols to layer.
}
```

I have reference to `IGeoFeatureLayer` but that does not help in adding all these symbols to layer.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it by following -

```
IEnumStyleGalleryItem enumStyleGalleryItem = styleGallery.get_Items("Marker Symbols", filePath, null);
enumStyleGalleryItem.Reset();
IStyleGalleryItem styleItem = enumStyleGalleryItem.Next();

IGeoFeatureLayer geoFeatureLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)pointsFeatureLayer;
ISymbol symbol;
IUniqueValueRenderer uniqueValueRenderer = new UniqueValueRendererClass();
uniqueValueRenderer.FieldCount = 1;
uniqueValueRenderer.set_Field(0, "Tooltip");

while (styleItem != null)
 {
     symbol = styleItem.Item as ISymbol;

     uniqueValueRenderer.AddValue(styleItem.Name, null, symbol);
     geoFeatureLayer.Renderer = (IFeatureRenderer)uniqueValueRenderer;

     styleItem = enumStyleGalleryItem.Next();
}
```